# mvc:annotation-driven Spring mvc 3 and Tuckey URL Filter

Tags: spring-mvc, url-rewriting, annotations, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I was using Tuckey url for url re-writing. This is how it looks:

rule
        from / from 
 to /pf/welcome to 
        (changed format to enter into this forum, regular xml tags are used) 
rule

and this is how I have my entitymanager set up in web.xml:

OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
      /*</url-pattern>-->
          /pf/*
     FORWARD

I would like to take advantage of Spring 3 validations.
In my presentation-context file I added this:

As soon as I do that I get 404 errors. The mapping is off.

12/Sep/10 21:57:46 DEBUG [http-8080-1] DEBUG (org.springframework.web.servlet.Di
spatcherServlet.getLastModified(DispatcherServlet.java:842)) - DispatcherServlet
 with name 'dispatcher' determining Last-Modified value for [/PublicFountainWAR-
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/pf/welcome]
12/Sep/10 21:57:46 DEBUG [http-8080-1] DEBUG (org.springframework.web.servlet.Di
spatcherServlet.getLastModified(DispatcherServlet.java:850)) - **No handler found
in getLastModified
12/Sep/10 21:57:46 DEBUG [http-8080-1] DEBUG (org.springframework.web.servlet.Di
spatc**herServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:690)) - DispatcherServlet with
name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/PublicFountainWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
pf/welcome]
12/Sep/10 21:57:46 WARN  [http-8080-1] WARN (org.springframework.web.servlet.Dis
patcherServlet.noHandlerFound(DispatcherServlet.java:962)) - **No mapping found fo
r HTTP request with URI [/PublicFountainWAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/pf/welcome] in Dispat
cherServlet with name 'dispatcher'**
12/Sep/10 21:57:46 DEBUG [http-8080-1] DEBUG (org.springframework.web.servlet.Fr
ameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:677)) - Successfully complet
ed request
12/Sep/10 21:57:46 DEBUG [http-8080-1] DEBUG (org.springframework.orm.jpa.suppor
t.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.j
ava:120)) - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
12/Sep/10 21:57:46 DEBUG [http-8080-1] DEBUG (org.springframework.orm.jpa.Entity
ManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:328)) - Cl
osing JPA EntityManager

my controllers are mapped to key words without the "pf".
e.g. /welcome NOT /pf/welcome

the "pf" was just there to forward it to a sort of virtual path only known to the dispatchservlet for processing...the url's are all independant.

IS there a way to use Tuckey and ???

**Summary:**

guys any clues would help...just wanna add
mvc:annotation-driven

to my pre-existing spring mvc 3.0 web app using Tuckey URL filter......

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Tuckey because you have your Spring controller methods mapped to `/pf/*`, and you want to get rid of that part of the URL for the user.  You can do this without Tuckey.

Add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` [(see Spring Reference)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) to your Spring configuration and make sure your `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/` rather than `/pf/*` in `web.xml`.

The `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` was added in Spring 3.0.4, but it was not added to the schema `spring-mvc-3.0.xsd`, so it will show up as an error in Eclipse.  It does work despite the apparent error, and the problem is being addressed by [SPR-7545](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7545).

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, yes I did not want /pf in my urls rather, I just wanted my controllers to be unaware of any underlying implementation and just care about mappings like "/welcome" OR "/register" etc.  Another reason I went with Tuckey was I wanted to use restful URL's like /welcome/user/id/{userID} OR /welcome/hello/register/now/heyyyyy so I was ending up mapping every single restful URL in web.xml and it was getting to be huge and ugly..hence tuckey...so are you suggesting that it works the same way as I have it now just without Tuckey? I will give it a go as well...thanks!!!!

Comment: hi after trying this new technique, I am getting a problem with the mapping.  NO mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myProjectWebApp/welcome] I only require /welcome ....any ideas?